# GUI Tool to deny Standard users from Using CD-ROM and USBs?

Tags: usb, permissions, security, cd-drive

As a part of security policy we need to disable CD-ROM and USB access for normal users. Only root users should have the access.

I could do it by removing the user from the '**cdrom**' and '**plugdev**' groups in **/etc/group**.

But this needs lot of work if there is many users

**I NEED A GUI TOOL**!

Answer (score 2):

you can configure a policy agent. Check the following links for USB policy agent:

1. http://www.linux-usb.org/usb-admin.html
2. http://www.linux-usb.org/policy.html

NOTE: this is not a GUI solution

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround for disabling USB:

`sudo mv /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/usb/storage/usb-storage.ko /root`

and for disabling CDROM:

`sudo mv  /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/cdrom/cdrom.ko /root`

Comment: Wouldn't this also prevent admin users from using USB and CDROM?

Answer (score 0):

I found this DLP for linux (with source and video). I hope it helps also:

https://github.com/edwinbs/linux-edlp

and that's a demonstration

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-KKahJcfevk